# I need to disable responsive feature of a theme called Meet GavernWP

Tags: themes

This question is deleted. Actually this question was showing up in my google search results and it was ruining up my seo.

Answer (score 1):

The main theme css (http://www.bookelivery.in/wp-content/themes/MeetGavernWP/css/template.css?ver=3.5.2) you are using does everything through a fluid layout - so everything with percentages. Thus there's no way to remove the responsiveness without completely changing the theme. It seems to work quite well for a mobile size, the main issue being your large title image which doesn't resize, which is probably not what the theme intends you to use. Also you're contact form should look at using the css styles they have in the theme to use fluid sizes.